# Pointers, Struct, C++,Writing a new structure in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

Could someone explain me the following mistakes and tell me how to fix them (written as comments)?

The structure I have:

```
const int max = 1000;
const int MAX = 30;

struct student_t
{
    int k; 
    char* name[MAX];  
    char** bez[MAX]; 
};
```

With this function I must write a member of this structure(members<=1000) and bez. (<=30) for every member:

```
int write (student_t *field[max], int i)
{
    student_t *pointerfield= new student_t;
    printf("Number:....");  
    std::cin>>pointerfield->number;
    if (pointerfield->number>1 && pointerfield->k<999999)
    {
        if (binarsearch(&field[max],i,(pointerfield->number))!=-1)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nName:.....");
            readstr();
            pointerfield->name=readstr(); 

            // insupportable types of allocation of int to char* [30]

            std::cout<<std::endl;
            int counter=0;
            std::cout<<"Do you want to add bez.? j,n"<<std::endl;
            char a;
            std::cin>>a;

            if(a=='j' && counter<MAX)
            {
                std::cout<<"Bez.:";
                readstr();
                pointerfield->bez[MAX]=readstr();

                // char *  can not be converted into assignment to char ** 

                counter++;
            }
            // ...
```

Comment: Two constants that only differ in spelling are going to hurt. Also, I have seen macros called `max` and `MAX` that will mess with your code. Further, you should create a separate program where only those parts that really cause the problem are retained. This helps you focus on the problem and saves you questions like "What is `readstr()`?".

Comment: What is the intended purpose of that program?

Comment: I think your 'name' and 'bez' elements are not doing what you think they are doing. 'name' is declared as array of pointers (i.e. it would hold array of strings) and 'bez' as an array of pointers to pointers (i.e. array of arrays of strings).

Comment: readstr() is a function in my code that reads a char until the end of the line (ignoring spaces on the line).  The purpose of the program must be to add a structure element in an array with not much as 1000 members, in my struct stays 'bez' as array with 30 elements,because I must write characterstring using char and pointer too,because the sum of all char-strings have to be smaller or equal to 30 for every structure element.

I am not allowed to use any library functions,only printf,getchar,scanf,cin and cout from iostream and stdio.h

Comment: that is my new variant,and it fixes the problem with a little bit changes in the function,but with it the code isnt working.Are this down and my structure in the question post equal:
struct ver {
 char* bez;
};
struct student_t {
    int k;
    char* name;  
    ver* abslv[MAX]; 
    
};

Comment: The question remains: What **exactly** is `readstr()`? Include its code in your question, so that others can actually compile your code. However, this is just part of extracting a minimal but complete example, which you should do, too.